# ios - UITableView width not displaying properly

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autocomplete, uitextview

I can't seem to work this one out...

I'm creating an iOS app which needed autocompletetextview style boxes so I'm working around this by using a UITableView to display possible searches.

My problem is this, I have the data being added correctly however the size of my table view is not correct between storyboard and simulator:

[Story Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y97W.png)

As you can see in the storyboard I have set the width and constraints to match the TextField above the table view. When this is run however:

[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asrcn.png)

You can see in the screenshot that the table view size is a lot smaller than what it should be.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this could be or how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've set a leading and trailing constraint that will work for the 600 x 600 view in the storyboard but those values will conflict with your other constraints when in a view of a different size, causing your width equal widths constraint to break. You should look at the logs. I'm sure there are warning about breaking constraints.

Comment: @beyowulf That's a fantastic spot! Thanks a lot for your help I've managed to sort it now!